# Transducer flatten and uniq

Tags: javascript, recursion, ramda.js, transducer

I'm wondering if there is a way by using a transducer for flattening a list and filter on unique values?

By chaining, it is very easy:

```js
import {uniq, flattenDeep} from 'lodash';|

const arr = [1, 2, [2, 3], [1, [4, 5]]];

uniq(flattendDeep(arr)); // ->  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

But here we loop twice over the list (+ n by depth layer). Not ideal.

What I'm trying to achieve is to use a transducer for this case.
I've read Ramda documentation about it https://ramdajs.com/docs/#transduce, but I still can't find a way to write it correctly.

Currently, I use a reduce function with a recursive function inside it:

```js
import {isArray} from 'lodash';

const arr = [1, 2, [2, 3], [1, [4, 5]]];

const flattenDeepUniq = (p, c) => {
    if (isArray(c)) {
        c.forEach(o => p = flattenDeepUniq(p, o));
    }
    else {
        p = !p.includes(c) ? [...p, c] : p;
    }

    return p;
};

arr.reduce(flattenDeepUniq, []) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

We have one loop over the elements (+ n loop with deep depth layers) which seems better and more optimized.

Is this even possible to use a transducer and an iterator in this case?
For more information about Ramda transduce function: https://gist.github.com/craigdallimore/8b5b9d9e445bfa1e383c569e458c3e26

Comment: neither `flatten` nor `uniq` are good use cases for transducers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transducers don't make much sense here.  Your data structure is recursive.  The best code to deal with recursive structures usually requires recursive algorithms.

### How transducers work

(Roman Liutikov wrote a [nice introduction](https://dev.to/romanliutikov/understanding-transducers-in-javascript-4pdg) to transducers.)

Transducers are all about replacing multiple trips through the same data with a single one, combining the atomic operations of the steps into a single operation.

A transducer would be a good fit to turn this code:

```
xs.map(x => x * 7).map(x => x + 3).filter(isOdd(x)).take(5)
//  ^               ^                 ^               ^
//   \               \                 \               `------ Iteration 4
//    \               \                 `--------------------- Iteration 3
//     \               `-------------------------------------- Iteration 2
//      `----------------------------------------------------- Iteration 1
```

into something like this:

```
xs.reduce((r, x) => r.length >= 5 ? res : isOdd(x * 7 + 3) ? res.concat(x * 7 - 3) : res, [])
//    ^
//     `------------------------------------------------------- Just one iteration
```

In Ramda, because `map`, `filter`, and `take` are transducer-enabled, we can convert

```
const foo = pipe(
  map(multiply(7)), 
  map(add(3)), 
  filter(isOdd), 
  take(3)
)

foo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) //=> [17, 31, 45]
```

(which iterates four times through the data) into

```
const bar = compose(
  map(multiply(7)), 
  map(add(3)), 
  filter(isOdd), 
  take(3)
)

into([], bar, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])  //=> [17, 31, 45]
```

which only iterates it once.  (Note the switch from `pipe` to `compose`.  Tranducers compose in an order opposite that of plain functions.)

Note the key point of such transducers is that they all operate similarly.  `map` converts a list to another list, as do `filter` and `take`.  While you could have transducers that operate on different types, and `map` and `filter` might also work on such types polymorphically, they will only work together if you're combining functions which operate on the same type.

### `Flatten` is a weak fit for transducers

Your structure is more complex.  While we could certainly create a function that will crawl it in in some manner (preorder, postorder), and could thus probably start of a transducer pipeline with it, the logical way to deal with a recursive structure is with a recursive algorithm.

A simple way to flatten such a nested structure is something like this:

```
const flatten = xs => xs.reduce(
  (a, x) => concat(a, isArray(x) ? flatten(x) : [x]), 
  []
);
```

(For various technical reasons, Ramda's code is significantly more complex.)

This recursive version, though, is not well-suited to work with transducers, which essentially have to work step-by-step.

### `Uniq` poorly suited for transducers

`uniq`, on the other hand, makes less sense with such transducers.  The problem is that the container used by `uniq`, if you're going to get any benefit from transducers, has to be one which has quick inserts and quick lookups, a `Set` or an `Object` most likely.  Let's say we use a `Set`.  Then we have a problem, since our `flatten` operates on lists.

### A different approach

Since we can't easily fold existing functions into one that does what you're looking for, we probably need to write a one-off.

The structure of the earlier solution makes it fairly easy to add the uniqueness constraint.  Again, that was:

```
const flatten = xs => xs.reduce(
  (a, x) => concat(a, isArray(x) ? flatten(x) : [x]), 
  []
);
```

With a helper function for adding all elements to a `Set`:

```
const addAll = (set, xs) => xs.reduce((s, x) => s.add(x), set)
```

We can write a function that flattens, keeping only the unique values:

```
const flattenUniq = xs => xs.reduce(
  (s, x) => addAll(s, isArray(x) ? flattenUniq(x) : [x]), 
  new Set()
)
```

Note that this has much the structure of the above, switching only to use a `Set` and therefore switching from `concat` to our `addAll`.

Of course you might want an array, at the end.  We can do that just by wrapping this with a `Set -> Array` function, like this:

```
const flattenUniq = xs => Array.from(xs.reduce(
  (s, x) => addAll(s, isArray(x) ? flattenUniq(x) : [x]), 
  new Set()
))
```

You also might consider keeping this result as a `Set`.  If you really want a collection of unique values, a `Set` is the logical choice.

Such a function does not have the elegance of a points-free transduced function, but it works, and the exposed plumbing makes the relationships with the original data structure and with the plain `flatten` function much more clear.

---

I guess you can think of this entire long answer as just a long-winded way of pointing out what user633183 said in the comments: "neither flatten nor uniq are good use cases for transducers."

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ for the cleanup and the updated link!  At least one of those phrases you altered had been pretty horrible!

Comment: I just updated the link, the cleanup was from you :P

Comment: LOL.  I must have misread the history.  I'm glad I didn't leave text as bad as that!

Answer (score 1):

Uniq is now a transducer in Ramda so you can use it directly. And as for flatten you can traverse the tree up front to produce a bunch of flat values

```js
const arr = [1, 2, [2, 3], [1, [4, 5]]];

const deepIterate = function*(list) {
  for (const it of list) {
    yield* Array.isArray(it) ? deepIterate(it) : [it];
  }
}

R.into([], R.uniq(), deepIterate(arr)) // ->  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This lets you compose additional transducers

```js
R.into([], R.compose(R.uniq(), R.filter(isOdd), R.take(5)), deepIterate(arr))
```

Comment: Nice catch.  I'd forgotten this question when Ramda made `uniq` a transducer.