# Can reduce do everything that map does?

Tags: javascript, filter, functional-programming, reduce

I was in an interview and I was asked how to do this with JavaScript (kind of array manipulation) I said we can use `reduce`, but the interviewer said no we should use `map` but I am a bit sure that `reduce` can do anything that `filter` or `map` are doing. Am I correct or no?

Apologies, I can't reproduce the question I was asked, but I am asking here about the reducing technique generally in JavaScript...

Comment: in the same way that you can use your shoes to butter your toast, it's doable but the knife is more suitable for it

Comment: Yes, `reduce` *can* do everything `.map` can do. In fact, all the array iteration methods can be expressed in terms of `reduce`. That doesn't mean you *should* use `reduce` for all of them. Unless you are using [transducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008364/transducer-flatten-and-uniq)  (also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198833/how-to-chain-map-and-filter-functions-in-the-correct-order)) you shouldn't - it's way more clear what you actually mean when you use the correct idiom for the job. Not to mention easier to implement

Comment: You always can do everything, the moment you have a callback, in which you can write arbitrary code, which has the same privileges. That doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **ABSOLUTELY YES!**

Reduce can in fact do *anything* that can be done by single iteration.

Filter:

```js
myArray.reduce(
    (result, item) => [...result, ...(myCallback(item) ? [item] : [])],
    []
)
```

Map:

```js
myArray.reduce(
    (result, item) => [...result, myCallback(item)],
    []
)
```

That being said, if you need to filter the items, use `filter()` and if you need to map the items, use `map()`.

Comment: That being said, if you wrote that code in a job interview, you'd more likely not get taken. Also, i don't know why this abomination of using spread in these small snippets became so popular, it turns everything from O(n) to O(n²) - not just here, it's been all over SO for a while now.

Comment: Do you have a proof it's O(n^2)? Also, how often do you use arrays with thousands of elements? For anything under, it doesn't matter.

Comment: As long as the jitter isn't a lot smarter than i'd expect, and notices, that there aren't any references to the intermediate arrays, and therefore rewrites your code - you are copying the array on every step, and a standard sum from 1..n has an n² term, yes. You are correct, it very often doesn't matter. I just see it almost everywhere on SO these days, and i'd guess 1-5% of people using it will get in trouble, without even knowing why.

Comment: @VLAZ any proof it's faster?

Comment: A difference from O(n) to O(n²) is so blatant, that you can just use both for an ever larger array, and eventually, one will freeze your browser, while the other will finish in milliseconds.

Comment: @RoboRobok I recently wrote this little gist showing that spreading quickly slow your code starting with only 1000 items. See https://gist.github.com/customcommander/97eb4b3f1600773db59406d39f3f9cd7

Comment: Just as a mention though, `Array.prototype.concat` "does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array." - it's therefore the same as spreading. You have to e.g. `push`.

Comment: A typical demonstration would be the following: `const arr = [...Array.prototype.keys.call({ length: 20000 })]; arr.reduce((p, c) => (p.push(c), p), []); console.log("hey, i did finish!"); arr.reduce((p, c) => [...p, c], []);` (if you have a faster PC than i do, maybe you'll need 25000, but it will degenerate very quickly around that area - n² grows fast)

Comment: Also maybe for demonstration purposes, it was unwise to use spread to create the demonstration array - that's unimportant here, it just needs to be some array with 20000+ elements. You can use `Array.from({ length: 20000 }, (_, i) => i)` or even `Array(20000).fill(0)`.

Comment: Where did I use spread to create "demonstration array"? My demonstration array is `myArray`, which I never defined.

Comment: I was referencing to my previous comment, where i use `[...Array.prototype.keys.call({ length: 20000 })]`, and can't edit anymore. It's slightly unwise to include a spread operator in a demonstration about spread operators, that isn't necessary. It may distract from the important part. Even though that is an actual iterator, and not an array i am spreading there.

Comment: @VLAZ I made a quick test and `concat()` performed ~2.5 times **slower** than spreading. 12s vs. 5s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can but that doesn't mean that you should swap `Array#map` for `Array#reduce` for any single task.

If you meant to transform *all* items in an array, then `Array#map` is just more practical:

```js
[1,2,3].map(x => x + 10);
//=> [11,12,13]

// vs

[1,2,3].reduce((acc, x) => (acc.push(x + 10), acc), []);
//=> [11,12,13]
```

The canonical example for `Array#reduce` is to *reduce* a list to a single value. e.g., summing up the numbers in a list:

```js
[1,2,3].reduce((tot, x) => tot + x, 0);
//=> 6
```

If you meant to transform *and* filter at the same time then `Array#reduce` may be helpful:

```js
[1,true,2,false,3].filter(x => typeof x === 'number').map(x => x + 10);
//=> [11,12,13]

// vs

[1,true,2,false,3].reduce((acc, x) =>
  typeof x === 'number' ? (acc.push(x + 10), acc) : acc, []);
//=> [11,12,13]
```

Syntactically it could be argued that the `.filter().map()` approach looks prettier but it does iterate more than necessary: `.filter()` yields another array for `.map()` to consume.

If you have a big list to process, chaining array operations *ala* jQuery may be inefficient:

```
[items × 1000].filter(...).map(...).filter(...).map(...).filter(...);
// Depending on what you do at each step this could take a while
```