# Javascript ES6 Array.prototype.map() and Object.assign() for single line

Tags: javascript

**Assumption** (based on tutorials and reading material):
Example; https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Updating an object property in an array best practice is through map versus foreach.  Every example as per the redux breaks out map into two functions 1. Update object properties/s and return object. Even on medium and other expert content it follows this format

**Example:**

I'm iterating through an array of objects and updating every boolean active flag based on on whether that object's id property === id argument.

```js
let items = [{id:1,active:false},{id:2,active:false},{id:3,active:false}];

const traditional = (items,id) => items.map(item => {
        item.active = item.id === id;
        return item
    })

console.log("traditional ", traditional(items, 3));
// outcome:  [{id:1,active:false},{id:2,active:false},{id:3,active:true}];
```

**Question:**

I've been using a combination of Object assign and map to condense the code, but I'm told that is bad practice and should stop. What am I missing i.e. what's the problem with this approach?

```js
let items = [{id:1,active:false},{id:2,active:false},{id:3,active:false}];

const updateItemsById = (items,id) => items.map(item => Object.assign(item, {active:  (item.active = item.id === id)}))

console.log("update ", updateItemsById(items, 2));
```

Comment: I cannot see any good reason to use map instead of forEach if you do not need a new array. I see it as misleading.

Comment: Your `.map()` is still mutating each object. If your goal is to have a pure operation, then you can use `Object.assign({}, item, {active:  (item.active = item.id === id)})` - copy the object and overwrite `active`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Updating an object property in an array best practice is through map versus foreach. Every example as per the redux breaks out map into two functions 1. Update object properties/s and return object. Even on medium and other expert content it follows this format

This is generally true only if you really need a separate array. Your current logic is *mutating* the existing objects, and returning a shallow copy of the array. This is quite an odd thing to do, and is probably the source of why some may be frowning on your existing approach. Usually, you'd want to create a whole new array with new objects, instead of mutating the existing array - use rest syntax instead of `Object.assign` to keep things more concise:

```js
let items = [{id:1,active:false},{id:2,active:false},{id:3,active:false}];

const updateItemsById = (items,id) => items.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  active: item.id === id
}));

console.log("update ", updateItemsById(items, 2));
```

If you really intend to change the existing objects, then `.map` probably isn't appropriate - instead, use a generic iteration method like `for` or `forEach`, loop through the objects, and mutate them as needed. `for` and `forEach` loops are for generic side-effects.

```js
let items = [{id:1,active:false},{id:2,active:false},{id:3,active:false}];

const traditional = (items,id) => {
  for (const item of items) item.active = item.id === id;
};

traditional(items, 3);
console.log("traditional ", items);
```

Comment: Is there a reason for NOT using forEach in your second example?
`items.forEach(item =>  item.active = item.id === id);` I find it much more concise

Comment: Other than [`no-return-assign`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign) (which most won't care about), not really, both methods work fine. I use `for` iterators instead of `forEach` just out of habit, not out of any more concrete reason.

Comment: The reason I asked is that OP _specifically_ mentions _Updating an object property in an array best practice is through map versus foreach_ which I disagree on due to the name and waste of an array, but have not investigated otherwise

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks a million - makes perfect sense. One quick question. Would reduce be a better / similar approach for option 1 to avoid mutating the object e.g. accumulator.push(item)?

Comment: @Nolan No. 2 possibilities I see here: (1) Mutate the objects - in which case, use generic iteration method like `for` or `forEach`. (2) From a functional perspective, create a new array with new objects. The only appropriate method when creating a new array that's one-to-one with an old array is `Array#map`. While you *can* use other array iteration methods to accomplish the same thing, `.map` makes the most sense by far, since the input and output items are one-to-one.

Comment: @Nolan `accumulator.push(item)` would just be re-writing `.map` as a `.reduce`. It's *usually* not a good solution, unless you're trying to generalise over other operations array like [implementing a transducer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52010668/). Normally, replacing `.map` with an equivalent `.reduce` doesn't make much sense.