# How to "pass" extra data between chained maps and filters

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

This is mostly for academic interest, as I've managed to solve it an entirely different way, but, short story, what I want is, in pseudocode:

```
Foreach object in array1
    Find matching otherObject in array2 // must exist and there's only 1
    Find matching record in array3      // must exist and there's only 1
    If record.status !== otherObject.status
        push { otherObject.id, record.status } onto newArray
```

It intuitively seems to me there should be a way to do something with `array1.filter(<some function>).map(<some other function>`, but I can't get it to work in practice.

Here's a real-world example. This works:

```
function update(records) {
  const filtered = records.filter((mcr) => {
    const match =  at._people.find((atr) => atr.email.toLowerCase() ===
      mcr.email.toLowerCase());

    return (match.subscriberStatus.toLowerCase() !==
      mc.mailingList.find((listEntry) =>
        listEntry.id === mcr.id).status.toLowerCase()
    );
  });

  const toUpdate = filtered.map((mcr) => {
    const match =  at._people.find((atr) => atr.email.toLowerCase() ===
      mcr.email.toLowerCase());

    return ({ 'id': match.id,
              'fields': {'Mailing List Status': mcr.subscriberStatus }
            }
    );
  });
}
```

But what bums me out is the duplicated `const match =`. It seems to me that those could be expensive if `at._people` is a large array.

I naively tried:

```
function update(records) {
  let match;

  const toUpdate = records.filter((mcr) => {
    match = at._people.find((atr) => atr.email.toLowerCase() ===
      mcr.email.toLowerCase());

    // return isDifferent?
    return (match.subscriberStatus.toLowerCase() !==
      mc.mailingList.find((listEntry) => listEntry.id === mcr.id).status.toLowerCase());
  }).map((foundMcr) => {
    return ({ 'id': match.id, 'fields': {'Mailing List Status': foundMcr.subscriberStatus } })
  });
}
```

But (somewhat obviously, in retrospect) this doesn't work, because inside the `map`, `match` never changes — it's just always the last thing it was in the `filter`. Any thoughts on how to pass that `match.id` found in the `filter` on an entry-by-entry basis to the chained `map`? Or, really, any other way to accomplish this same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to *only* use `.map` and `.filter()` then you can avoid extra re-calculations later on in the chain if you do the following (generic steps):

1. `.map()` each item into a wrapper object that contains:

   - item from the array
   - calculate the extra data you would need in later steps
2. `.filter()` the wrapper objects based on the calculated data.
3. `.map()` the leftover results into the shape you wish, drawing on the original item and any of the calculated data.

---

In your case, this can mean that:

1. You do the find logic once.
2. Use the found items to discard some of the results.
3. Use the rest to generate a new array.

Here is the result with the callbacks extracted to make the map/filter/map logic clearer:

```
//takes a record and enriches it with `match` and `mailingStatus`
const wrapWithLookups = mcr => {
    const match =  at._people.find((atr) => atr.email.toLowerCase() ===
      mcr.email.toLowerCase());
    const mailingListStatus = mc.mailingList.find((listEntry) => listEntry.id === mcr.id).status;

    return { match, mailingListStatus , mcr };
};

//filters based on match and mailingListStatus calculated fields
const isCorrectSubscriberStatus = ({match, mailingListStatus}) => 
    match.subscriberStatus.toLowerCase() !== mailingListStatus .toLowerCase();

//converts to a new item based on mcr and match
const toUpdatedRecord = ({match, mcr}) => ({
    'id': match.id,
    'fields': {'Mailing List Status': mcr.subscriberStatus }
});

function update(records) {
    return records
        .map(wrapWithLookups)
        .filter(isCorrectSubscriberStatus)
        .map(toUpdatedRecord);
}
```

---

This saves the re-calculation of `match` and/or `mailingStatus` if they are needed later. However, it does introduce an entire new loop through the array just to collect them. This could be a performance concern, however, it is very easily remedied if you use lazy evaluated chain like what is provided by [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#lodash). The code adjustment to use that would be:

```
function update(records) {
    return _(records) // wrap in a lazy chain evaluator by Lodash ->-+
        .map(wrap)                         // same as before         |
        .filter(isCorrectSubscriberStatus) // same as before         |
        .map(toUpdatedRecord)              // same as before         |
        .value(); // extract the value <-----------------------------+
}
```

Other libraries would likely have a very similar approach. In any case, lazy evaluation does not run once through the array for `.map()`, then another time for `.filter()`, then a third time for the second `.map()` but instead only iterates once and runs the operations as appropriate.

---

Lazy evaluation can be expressed through a transducer which is built on top of `reduce()`. For an example of how transducers work see:

[How to chain map and filter functions in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44198833)
[Transducer flatten and uniq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52008364)

Thus it is possible to avoid all the `.map()` and `.filter()` calls by simply doing one combined function and directly use `.reduce()`. However, I personally find that harder to reason about and more difficulty to maintain, than expressing the logic through a `.map().filter().map()` chain and then using lazy evaluation, if performance is needed.

---

Worth noting that the `map()` -> `filter()` -> `map()` logic does not need to used via a lazy chain. You can use a library like the [FP distribution of Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) or the vanilla [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) that give you generic `map()` and `filter()` functions that can be applied to any list and combined with each other to avoid multiple repetitions again. Using Lodash FP this would be:

```
import map from 'lodash/fp/map';
import filter from 'lodash/fp/filter';
import flow from 'lodash/fp/flow';

function update(records) {
    const process = flow(
        map(wrapWithLookups),
        filter(isCorrectSubscriberStatus),
        map(toUpdatedRecord),
    );
    
    return process(records);
}
```

For Ramda the implementation would be the same - `map()` and `filter()` act the same across the two libraries, the only difference is that the composition function ([`flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#flow) in Lodash) is called [`pipe`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) in Ramda. It acts identically to `flow()`:

```
pipe(
    map(wrapWithLookups),
    filter(isCorrectSubscriberStatus),
    map(toUpdatedRecord),
)
```

For a deeper look at why you might want to avoid chaining and the alternative here, see the article on Medium.com: [Why using `_.chain` is a mistake.](https://medium.com/bootstart/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would do this, if this can help:

```js
let newArray = array1.filter((item) => {
   let matching1 = array2.filter(matchingFunction)  
   let matching2 = array3.filter(matchingFunction) 
   return matching1?.status == matching2?.status; 
})
```