# JS Is there a way to make this function smaller?

Tags: javascript

please tell me how to make this function smaller
how can i combine map reduse and if check in one function

```
const items = [
  { prise: 40 },
  { prise: -120 },
  { prise: "505" },
  { prise: 350 },
];

const isType = (item) => {
  if (typeof item.prise === "number" && item.prise > 0) {
    return item.prise;
  }
  return 0;
};

const sum = items.map((key) => {
  return isType(key);
});

const total = sum.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item);
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about refactoring working code, so it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Move the `isType` call into the reducer directly? `const total = items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + isType(item), 0);`

Comment: `sum.map(isType).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item)` but transducers might be more relevant. See: [Transducer flatten and uniq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52008364)  and [How to chain map and filter functions in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44198833) for examples.

Comment: btw, a function which starts with `is...` is ment to return a boolean value.

Comment: I know English it not everyone's native tongue here, but `prise` did you mean either `price` or `prize`..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a single function like so:

```
const total = items.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + isType(curr), 0);
```

```js
const items = [{
    prise: 40
  },
  {
    prise: -120
  },
  {
    prise: "505"
  },
  {
    prise: 350
  },
];

const isType = (item) => {
  if (typeof item.prise === "number" && item.prise > 0) {
    return item.prise;
  }
  return 0;
};

const total = items.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + isType(curr), 0);


console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [
  { prise: 40 },
  { prise: -120 },
  { prise: "505" },
  { prise: 350 },
];

const isType = (item) => {
  if (typeof item.prise === "number" && item.prise > 0) {
    return item.prise;
  }
  return 0;
};

const total = items.reduce(function (item, currVal) {
    return item + isType(currVal);
}, 0);

console.log(total)
```

Comment: `350 + 40` = `390`.. :),

Comment: Why the mutable variable `sum` tho?